# What is the proper academic term for "realizing sales from online traffic"?

Tags: definition, marketing

Realizing sales form traffic is one of the major concerns for firms in a digital economy. To my knowledge, online marketing methods (such as SEO) usually generate traffic but not necessarily profits. What is the academic term for the action of "realizing sales from online traffic" or "traffic to profit conversion rate"?

For example, if the daily view of a merchant's website is 1000, and the number of customers spending money per day is 2. Then the "traffic to sales conversion rate" is:
$$\frac{2}{1000}=0.002$$

Second Question: While this term is discussed in the recent works in digital economy, I wonder if this term also belong to the field of digital marketing.

Comment: ["Website monetization"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Website_monetization)? Or is that maybe too specific... are you looking for a term that encompasses mobile apps and other kinds of traffic?

Comment: “Online sales” fits, and there’s probably a dozen synonyms for that phrase. “Online sales” is a typical phrasing used in discussing retail sales.  It sounds like you want buzzwords from the digital marketing industry, and not from academic economists. The usual phrasings I’ve seen from digital marketing  is “conversions” (e.g. conversion rate) or “monetisation” (which is vague, as it can include things like advertising revenue).

Comment: Do you know for sure that there is actually such a term? Or are you just trying to look for a term that describes a quantity that represents the meaning "traffic to sales conversion rate"? If the former, it may help to explain the context under which you previously saw the term used; if the latter, you should feel free to coin your own term.

Comment: @HerrK. I just did more research. In digital marketing, Conversion Rate (CR) is the percentage of site visitors that complete a goal. The goal is usually (but not always) making money. In China, my home country, CR almost exclusively means "traffic to sales conversion rate".

Comment: Looks like you've found an answer. Feel free to put that in the answer box.